# Can you progress horizontally while making a high jump?

Tags: dnd-5e, movement

When you make a long jump, you can also (at DM's discretion, as mentioned in the rules) raise to a vertical distance up to a quarter of the horizontal distance covered (provided that you succeed in an Athletics check).

Is a similar thing possible while making a high jump ? (Cover a bit of horizontal distance during the high jump if a successful Athletics check is made)

Comment: out of curiosity, what situation (if any) prompted this question.

Comment: I am making a character that will be able to make very big jumps, and was curious about the possibilities involved.

Answer (score 4):

There is no rule for this, specifically. 
The following two rules generally apply to long and high jumps:

> Long Jumps can move a distance up to your Strength Score. (DC10 to clear a 1/4 length obstacle)
>
> High Jumps can move a distance up to 3 + your strength modifier.

I propose the following house rule ideas.

1. You can just travel one quarter of the height distance as a part of the jump. (jump 4 feet high, move 1 foot over)
2. Increase the difficulty of the check during a long jump to jump higher. (Maybe DC20 to clear 1/2 the distance as height?)
3. Calculate the difference in ballistic trajectory between your high-jump and long-jump abilities. (see Notes*)

Ultimately, this shouldn't come up a lot, so you should work with your GM to find the solution that works best for you and your game. Keep in mind that distance jumped counts as distance traveled. If you have a speed of 30, you can't run 20 feet and jump 11 feet.

Notes on Calculation*:
 <sub>With a Strength of 20, you can travel 20 horizontal feet or 8 vertical feet. With a Strength of 10, you can travel 10 horizontal feet or 3 vertical feet. It can be said that each foot available of vertical jump (V) is a function of available horizontal feet (H).
V = 3 + (H-10)/2 

So, with 20 feet available, jumping 10 feet horizontally leaves me 3 feet of available vertical movement.</sub>

<sub>PS - Just to be complicated, you could also take the percentage of jump you used and allow the remaining percentage to be applied to the other axis (horizontal vs vertical); jumping 75% of 20 feet, allows you to jump 25% of 8 feet and vice versa.</sub>

Comment: I like this calculation !

Comment: @GaelL it gets a little weird when you have less than 4 feet of horizontal movement left, but D&D has never been a very good physics simulator.

Comment: Have you tried using a rule similar to this before? If so, how did it work out? We always like answers based on actual experience if at all possible.

Answer (score 3):

The PHB description of jumping (p. 182) doesn't provide any mechanics for horizontal movement during a vertical jump. Neither the Dungeon Master's Guide nor Xanathar's Guide to Everything provide mechanics for that either.

You can certainly house-rule this sort of thing to be possible, though.

Comment: You could also discuss that if both could the other, then why have separate rules for both.